# How to check password while typing

Tags: html, angular, typescript, passwords

i want to build a website and need to make a change password site. How can i check the password while typing?

See this example with the infobox at the right side.

[image]

I use Angular2 and want to do that with typescript.

Comment: Just google model-driven forms for example.... here's one https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-angular-2s-model-driven-forms-with-formgroup-and-formcontrol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular has built in capabilities to validate input. You could use a regular expression to validate the password:

```
<div>
  <input placeholder="Enter your password" [(ngModel)]="password" #pwField="ngModel" type="password" pattern="[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]*">
</div>
<div *ngIf="!pwField.valid">Your password should contain at least one digit.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start to what you're trying - http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_intro